# Find two open intervals A,B⊂R such that (A∩B) closed ≠A closed∩B closed

Tags: general-topology

￼
Hi, I cannot come up with two open intervals in the reals that show the closed intersection of two sets does not equal the intersection of two closed sets.  Thanks!
￼￼

Comment: Consider the intervals $(0, n)$ and $(n, n+1)$. Or anything else of that type.

Comment: The closure of an open interval $(a, b)$ is $[a, b]$ - every open set containing $a$ or $b$ must intersect the interval and so the closure includes the endpoints. Now $(0, 1) \cap (1, 2) = \emptyset$, and this is closed already. But $[0, 1] \cap [1, 2] = \{1\}$.

Comment: @GuyPaterson-Jones you may want to write this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful for you to remember that certain sets are always closed.

Perhaps a bit more generally, what does closure do to open intervals, and why might the order of the closure and intersection operations be important?

Answer (score 0):

The closure of an open interval $(a, b)$ is $[a, b]$ - every open set containing $a$ or $b$ must intersect the interval and so the closure includes the endpoints.

Now $(0, 1) \cap (1, 2) = \emptyset$, and this is closed already, so the closure of the intersection is just the empty set. But $[0, 1] \cap [1, 2] = \{1\}$.

Comment: Why the downvote?